# Microsoft Windows 7 Debug/Checked Build

Tags: windows-7, windows

Has anyone installed this version of windows **Microsoft Windows 7 Debug/Checked Build**? It sounds interesting to me as it can be more steady and it is more software understandful (personally I don't how much useful it will be for me) on the other hand it is more slower.Any opinions on should I or shouldn't install this os .

Comment: The checked build is for software developers. And it's sometimes unhelpful (I seem to recall that some stuff in .NET's `System.Drawing` namespace is wrong and you get failures that you can't do anything about since you can't control the code in the .NET BCL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debug build is only useful for driver developers. It comes with additional checks and without compiler optimizations to debug bugs in drivers more effective.

MS explained it here in this article:

***Checked and Free Build Differences***

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx